# ARC and "copy" method

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I'm using SBJson to parse JSON strings.

Like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = received_notification.object;
```

Should I use

```
NSString *name  = [[dict valueForKey:@"name"] copy];
```

or

```
NSString *name  = [dict valueForKey:@"name"];
```

I think that first method copies NSString and after that dict can be released.

But for the second expression "name" keeps a reference to dict and it can't be released.

Am I wrong?

Comment: @CodenameLambda1 No, he ins't correct, i'm writing an answer

Comment: Note that `objectForKey:` is the main method to retrieve dictionary values. `valueForKey:` is only used for Key-Value Coding magic.

Comment: @MartinR you are right, I added it in my answer (with "credit" :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in the first case, and copying can be useful because `NSString` has a mutable subclass (`NSMutableString`), so `copy` ensures that you have a real `NSString` in `*name` and not it's mutable subclass.
(More: Talking about `NSString`, `copy` is used mainly on properties, but depending on how is structured your code can be useful even on a local variable)

But in the second case you are wrong.
First thing: you are using ARC (not mentioned in the post but I see the tag), so all local variables are `__strong` by default

When you do:

```
NSString *name = [dict objectForKey:@"name"]; // use objectForKey since valueForKey is for KVC, as suggested by Martin R
```

You are not taking a reference to the dictionary, but you are taking a reference to the object at the key "name" inside the dictionary (that should be an `NSString`).
So, ARC sends a `retain` message automatically to the `NSString`.
At that moment, that string is referenced strongly *at least* by two things:
- your `*name` pointer
- the `NSDictionary`

if your dictionary is deallocated, the `NSString` instance has another reference (from `*name`) and is not released until this last reference is removed.

Last thing: since in your example there are only local variables, all strong references created here are lost after the method ends (since the local variables are destroyed).
The referenced objects are deallocated if they have no other strong references in other parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks. So I can simply avoid "copy" in my example above and not worrying about memory?Then I'm putting "name" in my data base and after some time I'm replacing data.

Comment: If you are sure that the passed value is an NSString (and can't be an NSMutableString) you can avoid copying. But I don't understand what you mean in your second question :-) if you do `NSString *name  = [dict objectForKey:@"name"];` and, after, replace the content of *dict, the content of *name is preserved. However, since you are using local variables, the content is preserved until the current method returns. If you want the reference to persist, you have to use an instance variable.